# What is the best way to browse the web safely?

Tags: safe-browsing

At the recent pwnown we saw every single browser, from IE to Chrome, miserably hacked. That scares me. How should we browse the Internet safely but continuing to enjoy it? (using lynx is not an option)

Virtual machines?
Different users with non-administrative privileges?
Keep the work and "Facebook" on 2 separate machines? (or on 2 hard disks, invisible each other?)

I think that they should write a book on the matter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, I did not hear Chrome was as easily hackable as the rest.

But to answer your question: a virtual machine is the ultimate sandbox - basically like browsing on another computer (although both VMWare and VirtualBox had guest-to-host leaks in the past, they constantly upgrade their security, and I doubt it was browser related anyway).

Another approach is to use a sandbox software. In the past, I used [Sandboxie](http://www.sandboxie.com/) for a while. Today I simply use a different browser for my FB and other "we love 3rd party ads and cookies" sites.

Finally, consider running in private/incognito modes on sites you don't trust (which should probably be about 90% of the Internet :)).